# Codename One How to disable SMS default permission

Tags: codenameone

I sent a new update on Google Play Store but it was rejected due to Sensitive permission like SMS and when check AndroidManifest file i found it contain this code

`<receiver android:name="com.codename1.sms.intercept.SMSListener" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true"> <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647"><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />`

Although I don't need it inside my app but I think it's added by default.

And this is my list cn1 lib:

- cn1-codescan
- CodenameOne_SRC
- GoogleMaps
- QRScanner

**How I can disable these permissions so that I can send a new update?**

Answer (score 1):

This was probably added by a cn1lib you no longer use. That code is probably somewhere within your `codenameone_settings.properties` and you can just remove it.

Notice that if you will migrate to maven then removal of old dependencies will clean up their properties "noise" implicitly.